# How to run qubes os on KVM

Tags: virtual-machine, linux-kvm, qubes-os

Is there a way to get Qubes OS working in KVM, it freezes short after into boot, I tried to boot into new kernel but result is still the same.

Answer (score 1):

This subject is discussed in the Support post
[Trouble running Qubes on KVM/QEMU](https://forum.qubes-os.org/t/trouble-running-qubes-on-kvm-qemu/13318),
where it got a negative answer :

> I tried running Qubes on KVM/QEMU, but it didn’t work. Is it even possible to do that? I just want to test the OS without reformatting the whole computer.

The answer was a quote from the Qubes OS Installation Guide :

> **Note**: Qubes OS is not meant to be installed inside a virtual machine as a guest hypervisor. In other words, **nested virtualization** is not supported. In order for a strict compartmentalization to be enforced, Qubes OS needs to be able to manage the hardware directly.

The final advice was :

> Your options are:
>
> - Install on another (external) drive
>
>   - Bear in mind that if your external drive is a USB drive, you won’t be able to take advantage of USB passthrough. Qubes OS will implode if
>     you do that. (No, this is not a Qubes OS vulnerability, as Qubes OS is
>     not designed to run this way. It’s the equivalent of removing the
>     internal boot drive once the machine has already booted.)
> - Get a cheap computer to try it on
>
>   - Make sure that it’s a 64-bit X86 CPU that has VT-x and VT-d in its instruction set, otherwise it won’t boot.

An option that wasn't discussed is to install Qubes OS to
a separate partition on the hard disk in dual-boot, but you
might there be taking risks with your current installation.